# Apache Camel - transaction in routes

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a general question about Apache Camel. I wasn't able to find whether the aggregator is transacted. If it is transacted, how the transactions are implemented and how fast the aggregation is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sending the messages into the aggregator can run in a transaction.

You would need a persistent store with the aggregator to let the outgoing messages act as a transaction. See the documentation about persistence
http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2

For example there is a JDBC based and HawtDB (file based) persistent support out of the box. Its pluggable as you can also build your custom.

Camel in Action book chapter 8 and 9 convers this in much more details.

Comment: And what if I want to read messages from a JMS queue, process them and than return to the same queue in case of an error. The persistent store can't do that, can it?

Comment: No JMS queues dont fit well as a persistent store for aggregating messages. The store need to support both currently in progress of being aggregated messages, as well as completed aggregated messages, but currently in flight etc. But there is a pluggable API so you are welcome to code a custom store yourself